# Flutter mocking Firestore service for testing & directory structure

Tags: integration-testing, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am using Firestore and Redux. As such, I have a `firestore_service.dart` file that is the sole interface to Firestore and this same file updates the Redux store. For testing purposes I have created `firestore_service_mock.dart` along with a mock data file in the project test folder. My question is related to directory structuring and importing for testing purposes.

`main.dart` is the only file that imports `firestore_service.dart`. If I have `firestore_service_mock.dart` in the project test folder, then how do I import it into `main.dart` for integration testing? Not sure I am explaining myself clearly, so I hope this makes some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
import 'package:my_flutter_app/main.dart`;
```

`lib/main.dart` can be imported from everywhere inside your project (like with all files in `lib/`.

Comment: Thank you. I had such a mind block just trying to import test files into `lib/` vs the other way around. Glad I asked!